# Django 3.1.1 NOT NULL constraint failed with Date

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm getting this error on Django 3.1.1 while trying to define a model with an optional date field:

```
class Tickets(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("TicketCategories", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='ticket_category')
    openDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    closeDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tickets"
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} {self.subject}"
```

In this case `closeDate` should accept null and the user should be able to leave it empty on the admin panel.
Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: api_tickets.closeDate
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you migrate your model changes

Comment: Of course I did, but when I change any option in the DateTimeField parentheses and I try to makemigrations it just tells me 'No changes detected'. Can this be the source of my pain?

Comment: you still have not null constraint for some reason in your database, did you edit/delete any of your migrations? you can manually edit  out constraint

Comment: How can I manually edit constraint?